# Android app that updates Google spreadsheet

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I want to create an android app that allows multiple users to connect to a Google spreadsheet enter data into this single sheet through the app. Would I have to create a public sheet? If so would it require authentication or just a url of the sheet. If it is private sheet how what is required for authorization. I have read about the spreadsheet API but I don't where to start. Which would be easier a public or private sheet. Any guidance about how to go about this is welcome

Comment: Did u got any success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use google-apps-script or the google-spreadsheet-api 3.0 (GData). But I 
suspect  the google-spreadsheet-api is what you want. Google-apps-script is like VBA
and runs on google servers.

For GData, the CellDemo.java gives a good overview of the features.
https://gdata-java-client.googlecode.com/svn-history/r51/trunk/java/sample/spreadsheet/cell/CellDemo.java

Note: there is no INSERT row, only APPEND row. with GData - google-spreadsheet-api 3.0

I have never used a public sheet, not sure.
For a private sheet, you need OAuth2 or an Application password.

Comment: Since there are multiple users. how would authentication work. Is it possible for each of them to authenticate with their own account but still be able to access the same spreadsheet.

Comment: This looks like two independent problems. To authenticate, you can use OAuth2/OpenID. You can use an OAuth2 Token to read/wite to spreadsheets in a google drive account. Another options might be a shared google drive folder.